# Analysis of multivariate ranking data

Tags: joint-distribution, multivariate-regression, ranks, ordered-probit

I have data on companies, each company ranks how important are the following 4 elements (price leadership, quality, innovation, and customization) for its competitive strategy.

There are 4 dependent variables, each capturing the (relative) importance of one of the 4 elements of the competitive strategies for the focal company. The relative importance of the 4 elements is measured by a rank. The element with rank 1 is the most important one, the one ranked fourth is the least important one in the competitive strategy of the company.

I would like to investigate how a set of independent variables X (company characteristics) affect the importance of the 4 elements making up the competitive strategies. My Xs are company characteristics, features of the decision maker (size, industry, numbers of years in operation, type of ownership), and not features of the choice to be made (as in conjoint analysis).

An example of the data is provided below:

| Id | Price | Quality | Innovation | customization | Company size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 150 |
| : | : | : | : | : | : |
| N | 2 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 15 |

I understand that the ranks of the competitive strategies are interdependent, once the rank of the first 3 elements is known, the ranking of the 4th element is determined (the four variables containing the ranks of the 4 elements always sum to 9 across individuals).
Therefore the four variables containing the rans of the 4 elements of the competitive strategy needs to be analysed jointly.

I initially thought of a straightforward use of a quadrivariate ordinal probit model (each with 4 levels representing the 4 ranks), which allow to estimate the correlation among the residuals in the 4 equations. But then I started to doubt myself.

The doubt arises because of the analogy with the multinomial logit or probit in which the results can only be interpret with reference to a base category. If the research question would have been “which of the competitive strategies is the most important one?” (changing the data so that rank 1 is retained but ranks 2 to 4 are set to 0, also an instance of ipsative data in which the four variables add up to 1 across individuals) the much simpler multinomial logit or probit model should be used. In these models, the coefficients on the Xs are interpreted as differential effect on the choice of the focal alternative relative to a base category.

If the “relative to a base category” is the only way to interpret the results, maybe on could take one of the elements as a “reference element” (say price leadership) and then compute the difference in rank between the importance of the remaining 3 strategies from the reference strategy. In this way the 3 remaining variables no longer add to a constant across individuals. See below an example based on the data described above.

| Id | Price (reference) | Quality | Innovation | customization | Company size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | - | +1 | +2 | +3 | 5 |
| 2 | - | -1 | -2 | -3 | 150 |
| : | : | : | : | : | : |
| N | - | +1 | -1 | +2 | 15 |

The variables capturing the difference in importance of the remaining 3 elements from price now ranges from +3 to -3, and these data could be modelled by a trivariate ordered probit (with 7 levels).

Could anybody suggest how to go about the analysis of these data or direct me towards the relevant literature that would help me to choose the way forward?

I have looked around in geology (composition of rocks adding up to 100), in psychology (forced ranks, assigning 100 points to various items), chemistry (composition of compounds), but the techniques developed there are not meant to be used with regressors, they are for classification purposes. I cannot seem to find a model that can be used for a problem that is similar to mine.